# How to add a node tooltip to a networkx graph visualized with gravis?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have created a directed graph from a Pandas dataframe using NetworkX:

`graph = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'source', 'target', create_using=nx.DiGraph())`

To visualize the graph I am using the d3 function from the package [gravis](https://robert-haas.github.io/gravis-docs/index.html):

`gv.d3(data=graph, node_size_factor=2.0, node_hover_neighborhood=True, node_hover_tooltip=True, edge_size_factor=0.75, edge_curvature=0.3, layout_algorithm_active=True, use_many_body_force=True, many_body_force_strength=- 300.0, many_body_force_theta=0.9, use_many_body_force_min_distance=True, many_body_force_min_distance=50.0, use_many_body_force_max_distance=True, many_body_force_max_distance=250.0, use_links_force=True, links_force_distance=50.0, links_force_strength=0.5, use_collision_force=True, collision_force_radius=35.0, collision_force_strength=0.5, use_centering_force=True)`

The d3 function offers the possibility to activate the "Node hover tooltip" characteristic. According to the documentation if True, hovering a node leads to popping up a tooltip if the hover property in the metadata of this node contains a non-empty string or HTML text.

My question is: how do I assign such a hover property to the nodes of my graph? If I hover over a node, no tooltip information is found.

I tried adding an attribute 'name' to the nodes via following code:

`for node_id in graph.nodes: node = graph.nodes[node_id] node['tooltip'] = node_names[node_id]`

The code itself works and adds "tooltip" as node attribute but it does not change anything in the displayed graph.
Also I tried using the set_node_attributes function from NetworkX but it did not work either.

Thanks for any ideas on this!

Comment: Using `node['hover']` instead of `node['tooltip']` should work.